# tell me the meaning of this line "you might as well choke getting yourself born"

Tags: meaning, grammar, literature

I have a question from "A Day No Pigs Would Die."
I can't get the grammatical usage and exact meaning of the following lines

> “Calf,” I said to him, “you stay up your ma’s hind-side and you’re
> about to choke. So you might as well choke getting yourself born.”

Context: the character, Robert, is helping a cow give birth. Both the cow and calf seem to be in danger and may die if Robert doesn't help.

"So you might as well choke getting yourself born"
I don't understand this part in particular.
I am torn between these two meanings. Or is it neither of these two?

・Robert said rather the calf die if the calf wasn't willing to be born. (Of course, he doesn't think actually)
・Robert told the calf to come out on his own rather than die

Comment: If you stay where you are, you won't get enough oxygen.  So it's worth the risk of being deprived of oxygen during delivery.

Comment: @aparente001 Yes. Of course, the calf has no knowledge of this, which makes me wonder what literary device is in play: addressing someone, but in reality only reassuring yourself.

Comment: @Zan700 - If you want a literary device, I suggest you ask for it explicitly.  There are people here who really know their literary devices.

Comment: I know my literary devices, and if I thought five minutes about it, I could answer my own question. But I have a sore neck, which gives me a headache, and a buzzing in the ear, and, if you're familiar with Vonnegut's Harrison Bergeron, that disrupts my thought process. Exercising my newfound power, I'm closing my question before I open it.  End Man, October 22

Comment: The literary device is anthropomorphism -- ascribing human-like intention and understanding to the calf. @Zan700

Comment: But is it even a literary device? I think it's just something people do. If you're having trouble opening a jar, you might say "Why won't you open?" as if the jar is being deliberately stubborn and you could argue with it.